# Setting a linux variable to a command line output

Tags: linux, hex, dd

I am using QNX to modify some files and then output some information abou those files.  the process is similar to the following:
find certain files in a directory
if the names are less than a value
  perfomr dd command
  output file - info - staus

```
find $DIR -type n \( ! -iname "*sub*" \) -exec basename {} |
while read fname
do
    if [ $(printf '%d\n' 0x$fname) -lt 31 ] #if file is < 31
    then 
        dd bs=1 skip=67 count=1 if=/path/$fname/random of=/tmp/$fname
        echo -n " "$fname"      "  #output file name
        TEMP=$(</tmp/$fname)       #temporary file is in 
        hd -A x /tmp/$fname | gawk '{printf $2}'

        if [ $fname == 06 ]; then
            COM="Testing on 06" # this is temporary
        elif [ $fname == 08 ]; then
            case "?? hex value of $2 ?? in
                00) COM="DOWN" ;; #again, not sure what works
                0x01) COM="UP" ;;
                02) COM="Pass Through Mode" ;;
                *) COM="ERROR" ;;
            esac
        else 
            if [[ $STATE = 0x00 ]]; then #doesn't work either
                COM="DOWN"
            elif [ "(hd -A x /tmp/$fname | gawk '{printf $2}')" == 0x01 ]; then
                COM="UP"
            else
                COM="ERROR $STATE "
            fi
        fi

        echo "        " $COM



    fi
done
```

I need a comparison to be able work between the hex value of the dd output and a hex digit, or even integer comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

You can store results, sent to stdout from particular command in variable by enclosing it in ` quotes:

```
linecount = `cat text.txt|wc -l`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks to capture the output of a unix command into a unix variable, ie

```
   t=`/bin/date`
   echo the time is $t
```

You can probably do something like this

```
   firstByte = `dd bs=1 skip=67 count=1 if=/path/$fname/random of=- | hd -A x`
```

although you will need some additional arguments to `hd` to suppress the address info (I assume that is what you are trying to do with the `gawk` step. I don't know hd well enough -- read the man page.